# Golang. Как описать интерфейс для структуры, передающейся в методы по указателю?

Tags: golang, интерфейс

Допустим есть такая программа:

```go
package main

import "fmt"

type Number interface {
    GetInt() int
    SetInt(int)
}

func mult(number Number, k int) {
    number.SetInt(number.GetInt() * k)
}

type MyStruct struct {
    val int
}

func (m MyStruct) GetInt() int {
    return m.val
}

func (m MyStruct) SetInt(x int) {
    m.val = x
}

func main() {
    m := MyStruct{5}
    mult(m, 10)
    fmt.Println(m.GetInt())
}
```

Она работает некорректно, потому что в методы структура передается не по указателю. Но если добавить указатели в методы структуры:

```go
func (m *MyStruct) GetInt() int {
    return m.val
}

func (m *MyStruct) SetInt(x int) {
    m.val = x
}
```

То тогда как правильно добавить их в описание `interface`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так как вы меняете свойство структуры, то вам нужен указатель на структуру, как вы и сказали

```
func (m *MyStruct) GetInt() int {
    return m.val
}

func (m *MyStruct) SetInt(x int) {
    m.val = x
}
```

теперь вам нужно работать с переменным этой структуры в виде указателя

```
m := &MyStruct{5}
mult(m, 10)
fmt.Println(m.GetInt())
```

я бы посоветовл реализовать метод Mult тоже. Потому что оно меняет свойство вашей структуры.

```
type Number interface {
    GetInt() int
    SetInt(int)
    Mult(int)
}

type MyStruct struct {
    val int
}

func (m *MyStruct) GetInt() int {
    return m.val
}

func (m *MyStruct) SetInt(x int) {
    m.val = x
}

func (m *MyStruct) Mult(x int) {
    m.val *= x
}

func main() {
    m := &MyStruct{5}
    m.Mult(10)
    fmt.Println(m.GetInt())
}
```